# How to use multiple threads in Javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I was wondering how can I start, join and detach threads in JS.

I saw information about Service Workers, which are meant to run as separate processes in the background, not exactly what I'm looking for. Is there something else? How can I use it?

Comment: JavaScript (in the common engines) is single threaded. So if you need to distribute tasks among different CPUs then you need to use workers or child processes.

Comment: @t.niese - No, JavaScript isn't single-threaded. Most environments run a single thread per global environment (sometimes sharing that thread across more than one global environment), which is different from the language being single-threaded.

Comment: @Archer I think possibility of serial up voting? +1 on your comment

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=4s) helps explaining the event loop. 
Some methods like `fetch` will run asynchronously in their own thread and return a promise.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want [*service* workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), but rather web workers ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) | [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)) on browsers or [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) on Node.js.

Comment: I will look into it, probably was on the wrong path, thanks

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript in the main window runs on a single thread, it can run asynchronous functions that will turn to progress in the same thread. See:

- JS Concurrency model: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop
- JS Async function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

This two APIs will allow you to run different threads:

**Web Workers** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API (run and die kind of script thread execution) example:

```
var myWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
myWorker.postMessage('Message posted to worker');
```

**Service Workers** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API (run in the background between the network and the application)